# Using C# & LINQ, how do I speed up a GroupBy then Sum?

Tags: c#, linq

Thanks for looking.

I have a data structure that is something like this:

```
Flight #  | Airport | Tickets Sold
----------------------------------
123       | SEA     | 4
432       | SFO     | 2
9875      | SEA     | 1
33        | CLT     | 3
```

In reality, my table has about 20k records and I need to determine which airport has the highest total tickets.

I currently am using the following code which works, but is EXTREMELY slow:

```
    var mostTickets = flights.GroupBy(g => g.OriginAirport.IATA_Code)
        .Select(s => new {s.Key, Sum = s.Sum(su => su.Tickets), Airport = s.Select(se => se.OriginAirport)})
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Sum).First();
```

<strike>I have determined that the `GroupBy` call is quite fast, but everything down stream of it, starting with `.Select` takes about 15 seconds for about 20,000 records.</strike>

It is the `GroupBy()` that is slow after all.

Is there some way to speed this up?

Comment: What happens when you take out `Airport = s.Select(se => se.OriginAirport)`?

Comment: How have you determined that the `GroupBy` is quite fast?

Comment: @artm--No difference when I remove `Airport = s.Select(se => se.OriginAirport)`.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Enigmativity--If you were guessing that my testing method was suspect, you were correct.  The `GroupBy` IS the culprit.  When I previously tested, I forgot to bring the grouping into memory.  Any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: Do the query in the database and bring back the results.

Comment: Instead of group by using OriginAirport.IATA_Code, can you group using the foreign key of the Airport Table?

Comment: Is this linq2objects or linq2entities/linq2sql? Assuming this is database-backed, is there an index on `IATA_Code` in the DB?

Comment: Are you using the Entity framework?

Comment: `GroupBy` in LINQ to Objects is probably not going to give you the performance you're looking for when aggregating the groups. It buffers all the input in RAM when you really doesn't need to in that case.

Comment: What is flights? Did you check what query is generated? Are you aware of laziness of LINQ? Are you using Entity Framework or LINQtoSQL?

Comment: @Euphoric: Flights is essentially the data structure I have already demonstrated above with the exception of a foreign key to an airport object (id, name, iata_code).  What part of LINQ laziness is specific to this problem and how to solve?  Entity Framework.  Now that your questions are answered I look forward to the help you can offer.

Comment: How can flights be data structure when you are talking about database and Entity Framework? You are not making any sense. Also, you did not answer the most important question : did you check what SQL query is generated from your LINQ query?

Comment: Where is the SQL? We can't guess at answers here because your question doesn't supply enough information, and you seem reluctant to provide more... If you need help establishing how to gather the generated SQL, feel free to ask...

Comment: This is not a SQL question, it is a LINQ question.  Apparently, there is no good answer to the question other than a SQL solution which was down voted below.  If I have to go into the SQL to construct a better LINQ query, I have already lost time and it was easier to just do it in SQL and be done.  It is amazing to me that people don't get that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you thought about setting up a view for that?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: This is more a comment rather than answer, dont you think?

Comment: Thanks, this is really the best solution as LINQ GroupBy is far too slow.  When I construct the same query in SQL, it takes less than a second.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt There must be something wrong with your LINQ then. Your complete inability to share any details with us made us unable to properly help you.

Comment: @Euphoric--I shared details above both before, and now after your comment.  Now I look forward to what positive contribution you can make here.  I would also suggest that you cancel your downvote of zackery.fix's answer as creating the view (function, technically) and importing it into EF is so far the best possible solution to the problem.  If you have a better solution, please share it so we can all benefit.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt You should stop guessing... Actually I downvoted this answer, primarily because it doesn't answer your question but represents a workaround in the absence of you providing further information with regards to your problem. It is also effectively a "link only" answer and therefore becomes susceptible to link rot. W3Schools is also a resource of dubious quality. A proper answer is self contained. This isn't.

Comment: @spender--I think it's good that you came back to educate as to why you down voted.  In absence of that, we are only left with guesses as to who downvoted (or why for that matter).  Your comment above as to your reason for downvoting is illustrative and educational.  Downvoting with no explanation is punitive and pointless if not a little lazy.

Comment: I gave this answer in response to the lack of research people do.  There are many ways to do what the OP was asking, and yes this is a work around, but its also a very viable solution to the problem.  Additionally, I refuse to reinvent information in the hopes to sound intelligent; instead Ill point you to the source.  You can all quote me on this if you like, and remember stackoverflow is not a popularity contest, but a place to help others and gain trust as a developer.  Happy programming!